# jqplot - how do I get axis ticks to show on lines in between the bars?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

This is what I would like to do.

[image]

my current options setting on axis:

```
  axes: {
  xaxis: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
    ticks: xticks,  
  },
  yaxis: {
    min:0,
    tickOptions: {formatString: '%1.0f'}
  }
},
```

`xticks` is an array of strings. I can only get it to work if I dont use a renderer and my custom ticks, but I want to use my own specified ticks.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fighting the `CategoryAxisRenderer`, I'd fudge it with the default numerical one:

```
var chartData = [[1.5, 2.61], [2.5, 5.00], [3.5, 6.00]];

var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [chartData], {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {barWidth: 50}
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            ticks: [[0,"Midnight"],[1,"1 AM"],[2,"2 AM"],[3,"3 AM"],[4,"4 AM"]]
        },
        yaxis: {

        }
    }
});
```

Produces:

[image]

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RfKYp/).

Comment: hmm, this works, I see that you are sticking the bars in between the points.

Comment: I mean, the bars appears on lines by default if you dont use categoryaxisrenderer, so you manually shifted them over using a 2D array ``[[1.5, 2.61], [2.5, 5.00], [3.5, 6.00]]`` I ended up switching to a line graph, but thank you anyway. accepted

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it (not really a nice way I think) it's to use CSS.
You can move to your left the xaxis bloc thanks to `jqplot-xaxis` :

```
.jqplot-xaxis{
     left: -15px;
}
```

If someone have a better way to do it (in ticks options), I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: I've tried that but unfortunately my chart has to display in different sizes so this method doesn't work. thanks anyway